# Limitations of botnets

Tags: malware, botnet, ransomware

My question is very closely related to [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/43216/53519) but I didn't find my answer there. Specifically, I'm interested in whether the C2 server can modify aspects/properties of the malware and, if so, without letting the victim know.

The malware I'm interested about is CryptoLocker so I'm not really able to do a dynamic analysis of what happens after the connection to the C2 server is established. The **actual information** I eventually need is whether the ransom Bitcoin amount displayed in the CryptoLocker form was synchronized across all instances (e.g. by getting this information from the C2 server) or whether it was static and dependent on each CryptoLocker instance, i.e. the sample of the malware. I know already that the encryption key, which encrypts the victim's local files, has been received from the C2 server and was stored in the victims registry. I didn't find evidence that this method has been applied in order to display the Bitcoin amount.

**The question is**, whether there would be other ways to dynamically adjust the amount of Bitcoins displayed to the victim. Whether it has actually been the case with CryptoLocker is secondary. Although it's a nice bonus, if somebody is able to provide an answer there.

Comment: Are you asking if it is possible for botnets to dynamically change per install? Yes, of course. But, are you asking about a particular variant of cryptolocker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many facets to your answer. Botnets do resort to innumerable possibilities for evading detection, and even secure communication with the C2.

*Can the malware update itself periodically?*

DEFINITELY. I have seen malware in the wild which contacts the C2 and downloads updates even every hour. But a daily update is pretty common. In essence, the already installed binary will download the new malware (exe) and replace itself with the new version, essentially changing the behavior overall.

*Can the malware update just the Bitcoin ransom amount?*

Yes. Now the nuisance could be dependent upon the kind of botnet. Perhaps the malware is trained to visit a rogue account on twitter at particular time of the day, and pickup the seed number from the tweet, which will ultimately define the ransom amount? Oh yeah, I would say someone is already doing that somewhere.

Note that I do not have specific experience with Cryptolocker but I would suggest not marrying yourself to one particular behavior.

Comment: That's exactly the answer to what I was asking for (see edited question). Regarding this, I think it is very likely, that the amount displayed is not hard coded and dependent on the time the sample was downloaded, but rather dynamically updated by the C2.

Answer (score 0):

Yes as long as they is communication with the server and the victim then they can remotely modify anything they have access too. Another way is to include some sort of function in the malware that would periodically change the amount that's displayed.